# Bulk Updates and Transactions using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

When attempting to perform updates on multiple records, calling DbContext.SaveChanges() wraps them in a transaction. However, this seems to not allow other users to save their data on the table being updated and they receive timeout errors.

Using EntityFramework v6.2.0 I tried to understand the behavior behind the scenes by creating an application where I retrieve multiple rows (typically around 800) from the database, update their properties (up to 6 properties per row), and then call DbContext.SaveChanges(). I log the generated SQL to an output window and see that my update operations are all being wrapped in a single transaction. On saves where there have been a large amount of records updated other users cannot perform operations such as updating on the same table.

The results from my code are as expected, the updates are performed. However the issue has come when other users have attempted to update a row in the same table through DbContext.SaveChanges() while my update operations are currently being run. In this case, a single row is retrieved using Entity Framework and updated, and then finally DbContext.SaveChanges() is called. However they receive a SQLException because their execution timeout expired. I suspect this to be something to do with my updates and the transaction that my updates are wrapped in locking the table while my update operations are performed.

Comment: So you want the readers to be able to read uncommitted (dirty) data?

Comment: What if the properties I am updating, I am positive nobody else will be touching? Is this so bad then? I am processing records and there are fields to mark who is processing and when. No user should ever need to touch these fields.

Comment: It's not a question of opinion, just requirements. Are you able to change database level settings (without negatively affecting other parts of your database)? If not, are you able to change the SELECT queries (i.e. add a NOLOCK hint)?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you mean when you say "change database level settings"? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

Comment: So from what I can tell EF 6 uses READ COMMITED by default. What I am failing to understand then is how does this have the effect I am seeing in my application? With regards to READ COMMITED the article states "Other transactions can still modify, insert, or delete data between executions of individual statements within the current transaction". Therefore I can't see how this is causing other calls to this same table to timeout.

Comment: Between statements. You have 1 statement (bulk update). You are seeing exactly what is expected.

Comment: Ok I see, I misunderstood the article when it said "between executions of individual statements", I took that to mean it would allow other transaction to do work between each individual update statement in my transaction. So I think my question may have changed a little bit. I am wondering if how I am updating all in one go is the best option or if there is a better alternative (performing smaller batches of updates at a time to give the table "room to breath").

Comment: Well I've made 2 suggestions that would resolve your issue, but if they won't fit your situation you're certainly free to do more research on your own. Good luck!

Comment: If you want to mix large updates with frequent reads, then Snapshot isolation is a good option, but do read up on the different isolation levels. Snapshot isolation incurs a storage cost, and heavy use of the TempDB. It needs to be enabled at the database level. (not EF) Dirty reads /w NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED can solve the problem but they can lead to issues where uncommitted changes are seen. If your code is the only thing updating data, and just via the SaveChanges call (no explicit Tx) then this likely won't pose a problem, but be aware of the risks if future changes introduce these.

Comment: If you can commit changes in smaller batches then this will help reduce your problem. Each batch will participate in the acquire/wait for locks, giving other operations a place in the queue. One caveat though is if one batch fails, any previous batches will remain committed so you have to handle that scenario depending on what this bulk update is doing. (can it be resumed? Or do previously committed changes need to be changed back?) With optimistic locking, a batch operation could timeout due to other database load.